# Error -24 Google Play app android

Tags: android, google-play

You are everytime helping me but now I couldnt find a good post speaking about my problem (or solving), so I hope you can help one more time...
Recently I uploaded my app to Google Play , everything is all right but when i upload new upgrades some users can´t update the version because they get an ERROR-24

It´s a free online app , when users uninstall the app and they install it again... then it works perfectly...so I am wondering if there is something I can do to fix it!

Thanks everyone!

it´s this error: 
http://appslova.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/android-error-24-google-play.png

Comment: I'm also having this error. Can't find any documentation on the error and google support is a nightmare. No information on update errors and it's impossible to get through to speak to someone. Has anyone been able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help you, but the error in my case was due to the sharedUserId value in the manifest being different in my update. Changing the value back to what it was before allowed the update to complete through Google Play. You must always use the same sharedUserId for all updates of an app once it's in the Play Store.